# Excel Barcode Scanner Column Data to Row

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a barcode scanner to do inventory with large quantities and I want to enter the data into excel. I can change the way that the scanner behaves after each scan to do things like tab, return, etc. but my big problem is that in order to efficiently provide the quantity I have to scan the item code (7 digits) and then scan the quantities from 0 to 9 in succession. Such that 548 is really 5, 4, 8 and when using excel it puts each number into a new cell. What I would like to do, but don't have the VBA chops to do it is to have excel check to see if the length is 7 digits or one digit. For each one digit number it should move the number to the next cell in the same row as the previous 7 digit number such that each successive one digit number is combined as if excel were concatenating the cells. Then it should delete the single digits in the original column and have the next row start with the 7 digit barcode number.

I hope this makes sense.

Example:

```
7777777
3
4
5
7777778
4
5
6
7777779
7
8
9
```

Should become:

```
| 7777777 | 345 |
| 7777778 | 456 |
| 7777779 | 789 |
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried anything at all to do this yourself?

Comment: Of course I have. I can't get excel to differentiate between the two lengths and then combine the single digits. I have tried many tactics but just don't know enough about manipulating excel in this way.

And of course the formatting on my example isn't working.

Comment: do you want to format like: | <7 digits> | <3 digits> | <7 digits> ....

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Look into worksheet events - `Worksheet_Change` is what you want here. It has a parameter `Target` which represents the cell which just got changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up my worksheet like this:

[image]

then ran the below code

```
Sub Digits()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i&, r As Range, j&
    With Columns("B:B")
        .ClearContents
        .NumberFormat = "@"
    End With
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Cells(i, 1)
        If Len(r) = 7 Then
            j = 1
            Do Until ((Len(r.Offset(j, 0).Text) = 7) Or (IsEmpty(r.Offset(j, 0))))
               Cells(i, 2) = CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value) & CStr(r.Offset(j, 0))
                j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If
        Set r = Nothing
    Next
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Cells(i, 1)) < 7 Then Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete
    Next i
    Columns.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and the results Ive got:

[image]

Comment: This is getting close. I think I can work from this helpful strategy. The only problem is that the "quantity" value can be anwhere from 1 to 999 so that means it is not a standard number of single digit numbers after the barcode.

Comment: @user2744867 that's not a problem with the code. The code was designed to work with your original complexity of the problem - and it did. Now, that you have provided more details I have updated my answer and gave you a new code which covers the case youve described in the above comment :) Here, on stackoverflow we accept answers which are helpful to us:)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with what you started but I think your newer solution will work better. Thank you so much mehow!

```
Sub Digits()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i, arr, r As Range
    Dim a, b, c, d, e
    Dim y
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Cells(i, 1)
        Set a = Cells(i + 1, 1)
        Set b = Cells(i + 2, 1)
        Set c = Cells(i + 3, 1)
        Set d = Cells(i + 4, 1)
        Set e = Cells(i + 5, 1)
        If Len(a) = 7 Then
            y = 0
        ElseIf Len(b) = 7 Then
            y = 1
        ElseIf Len(c) = 7 Then
            y = 2
        ElseIf Len(d) = 7 Then
            y = 3
        ElseIf Len(e) = 7 Then
            y = 4
        Else:
            y = 0
        End If
        If Len(r) = 7 Then
            arr = Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + y).Value
            Range("B" & i & ":F" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
        End If
    Next
    Cells.Replace "#N/A", "", xlWhole
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```